# Are there any performance disadvantages of using .if and .elseif in assembly?

Tags: performance, assembly, masm

I was wondering if the `.if` and the `.elseif` directives had any performance disadvantages when compared to using a series of `cmp` and `jmp` statements.

Thanks!

Devjeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, there is no performance disadvantage.

However, if you decide to use them all the time, you should probably check the assembler generated every once in a while to better understand what they are doing to your code. There may be rare instances the produced code is slightly less efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You are more probable to write a worse .if yourself actually. For instance, ".IF eax==0" is evaluated as :

```
test    eax,eax
jnz     label
```

it can't get better than this.

Comment: actually .if is the more experienced way :) When you can use masm directives, you should by all means do so. This would create better code. I would advice that you take a look at Masm's great directives closely. Invokes and macros are, amongst other things, very important ways to write good masm code.

Comment: Oh:). I always thought the .if directive was a simpler way, since I've worked with c++ and java

Comment: The holy grail of Masm programming : http://win32assembly.online.fr/tutorials.html Enjoy :)

Comment: The code above might not be optimal. If you had an arithmetic operation on eax before, like "add eax, ebx", the 'test eax, eax' is unnecessary. The '.if' hides this and should generally be avoided.

Comment: I strongly disagree, my experience says the opposite. I've been programming assembly for years and there not a single asm guru i've met that programs in masm that does not use masm directives like .if. Not one. What's even more, probably the greatest win32 asm guru, iczelion, uses it. That's more than solid proof on what should be avoided and what should not.

Comment: Also, .if is not testing every zero flag possibility but it handles comparisons, that's obvious. Of course, if you need to check the zero flag after addition (for some reason), you would need to do it different. But .if was not meant to do all sorts of things. It's just an if, not a zero flag checker.

Comment: Really. So anyone who writes assembler, but isn't using masm and .if can by your defintion not be a guru? Come on, just think about it. I would even argue someone who hasn't seen something outside x86 or win32 can't really be considered an expert in asm.

Comment: @SpyrosP: I have to admit, if you write a complete project in assembler as some kind of esoteric mental workout, directives like '.if' can be useful, but even then I would rather use macros (and use fasm, check it out). For any 'normal' use of asm - doing things with the hardware which can't be done in high level languages or optimizing small performance critical parts - you definitely don't want to use '.if'.

Comment: We are talking about software programming here i suppose, hardware follows its own rules. Also, what you call esoteric mental workout, assembly coders may call it a software protection or coding a big numbers library.

Comment: Of course people who do not use masm can be gurus, i know many as well. But from the people i know that use masm(and they are many), every single one of them uses masm directives and especially macros.

Comment: I was talking about writing a _complete_ project in assembly. Not some core routines of a software protection or big numbers library, where using assembly actually does make sense ;-) And I was talking especially about '.if' and the like, not general macros. There is still the fact that '.if' hides a instruction which may not be needed in a situation where you don't want a high abstraction level (otherwise you wouldn't use asm anyway) but full control over your binary. This is like using HLA, which even the author admittedly never used in real world projects.

Comment: And for the answer you gave: You wrote "it can't get better than this". If we can agree that "better" in this context means "shorter or faster code with the same semantics", your statement is wrong, since the test instruction may be omitted in some cases and not using '.if' would be "better". Now you could argue that "better" suddenly means "more readable and easier maintainable", but that case I would not use assembly at all ;-)

Comment: I will shock you with that, but better programming always means more readable and easier maintainable code. And suddenly, using .if eax == 0 is easier to read than test eax,eax. Don't know how it happened, probably after a meteor shower or something. Using another language for that is just an argument not worth discussing at all.

Comment: What you for, some reason, do not seem to understand is that .if is not to be used anywhere, probably you are not reading my comments at all. But, when you can use it, by all means follow the world's best assembly programmers(like iczelion certainly is), not some random stackoverflow comments. And now, i'm talking to people reading this discussion, so that they do not drop themselves into overwhelmingly bad programming practices.

Comment: Now, i would like to be shown an example where YOU CAN USE .if but NOT USING it is faster. But one where you can use it, not something ridiculous like add eax, ebx because that is not even a comparison.

Comment: Note that the question explicitly stated "performance". Further, answering with two lines of assembly stating "it can't get better" seem to indicate that you were well aware of that. But unfortunately in this context your statement is wrong, so of course _now_ it isn't about performance at all, only about readability :-) For the code: Make that a `sub eax,2` (which can be used as a comparison eax==2, where you want to keep the difference) followed by a `.if eax==0`. Just read that code on a random page (the fourth result if you google `masm ".if"`

Comment: One last remark: I have read all your comments and will read future comments, if you decide to make some, as I am always interested in learning something new. But I will not comment any further because it's getting offtopic: Please note that neither conjuring some guru who hasn't updated his site for nine years and claiming that he is unsurpassed nor the use of CAPS LOCK helps your case. But remove that 'it can't get better than this' and the downvote will go away :-) Or just downvote some of my best asm answers if you like, but read them, you might even learn something ;-)

Comment: Thanx, but i will definitely pass on your assembly answers :) Calling Iczelion "some guru" is just enough for me to stop responding as well, SO laughable(caps have to be used here), shows that you don't know who this person is and what is considered in the community. Maybe you will call Randall Hyde some guru as well, next, who knows. Also, I consider your downvote a prize for me, it only makes my point stronger, so thank you.

Comment: I have shown you a example where the usage of ".if" generates inferior code as you requested, care to comment on that and how that makes your point stronger?

Comment: No, I don't, your example was devastating to my points. Case dismissed.